# Expectation with delta function

Tags: expected-value, dirac-delta

In Bishop on page 219, the equality below is given. Unfortunately, I fail to see how one finds the mean $\mu_{a}$ of this distribution. I know the definition of expectation operator, but how does one obtain the most right equality in the bottom equation? Can someone enlighten me? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\int p(a)a\ da = $ (first equality in OP post)

$=\int (\int \delta(a - w^T\phi)q(w)dw)\ ada = $ (change odrer of integration)

$=\int (\int \delta(a - w^T\phi)ada)\ q(w)dw = $ ((4.146) in Bishop)

$=\int w^T\phi\ q(w)dw  $

UPD. Added comments and fix

Comment: This makes no sense: how do you justify making "$a$" disappear at the end, to be replaced by "$w^T\phi$"?  Are you sure you put the equalities in the order intended?  Regardless, a little explanation would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Updated my post